# PrimeFaces DataTable "No records found" when there are records

Tags: java, primefaces, datatable

I got dataTable defined as:

```
<p:dataTable var="account" value="#{customerBean.accounts}"
            id="accounts" lazy="true">
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{msg['editCustomerForm.accountNumbers.header']}" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{account.accountNumber}" />
            </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

And accounts are loaded in this method (called in @PostConstruct method)

```
 private void initAccounts() {
        accounts = new CustomLazyDataModel<Account>() {
            @Override
            public List<Account> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
                return accountService.getAccountsForCustomer(customerModel.getCustomer(), first, pageSize);
            }
        };
        accounts.setPageSize(10);
    }
```

CustomLazyDataModel is there only because of this bug: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1544 (see comment #23)

But when page is rendered, component says "No records found."

SQL in hibernate log executed on the server returns 1 row and when i use dataList insted of dataTable result is corect (1 row is rendered).

```
<p:dataList value="#{customerBean.accounts}" var="account"
            id="accounts-old" rows="10"
            type="none" lazy="true">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['editCustomerForm.accountNumbers.header']}" />

        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{account.accountNumber}" />

    </p:dataList>
```

When using `<h:dataTable>` records are there also. So what is the problem with `<p:dataTable>`?

Comment: What is `CustomLazyDataModel`? Is that some your implementation?

Comment: According to PrimeFaces code, it prints "No record found" when your method `getRowCount()` returns 0. Are you sore that you set `rowCount`?

Comment: Yes, it is my implementation and only thing it does is overriding setRowIndex as shown in this comment http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1544#c23

Comment: Good point. When i call accounts.setRowCount(count); message "No record found" disappears, but still no record is rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only thing that was missing on the component was rows parameter.

```
<p:dataTable var="account" value="#{customerBean.accounts}" id="accounts" lazy="true" rows="10"  paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" >
```

Now records are rendered.